# Stock Quantity of ProductVariant not decreased in shopify shop when placing order via API

Tags: api, rest, shopify

I am posting the following Order to the shopify api Order endpoint. The Order shows up in the shop and everything works as it should, except that the stock quantity of the variants in orders placed via the API are not decreased automatically by shopify. When I place an order within the admin console, they are decreased automatically. Shopify inventory tracking is turned on for the products. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
  {
  "order": {
    "email": "someName@yahoo.com",
    "financial_status": "paid",
    "fulfillment_status": null,
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "note": "Created by someName",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 21718275463,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 99,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6820646151
      },
      {
        "variant_id": 21717700871,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 1000,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6820646151
      },
      {
        "variant_id": 21717690055,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 555,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "product_id": 6821668807
      }
    ],
    "processing_method": "offsite",
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Chris",
      "address1": "111 Love Road",
      "phone": "9999999999",
      "city": "St. Louis",
      "zip": "63123",
      "province": "MO",
      "country": "United States",
      "last_name": "Becker",
      "name": "Chris Becker",
      "country_code": "US",
      "province_code": "MO"
    },
    "source_name": "someName",
    "taxes_included": false,
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "title": "standard",
        "price": 0.00,
        "code": null,
        "source": "brand owner on shopify",
        "carrier_identifier": null,
        "tax_lines": null
      }
    ],
    "tags": "someName"
  }
}


    {
  "variant": {
    "id": 21718275463,
    "product_id": 6820646151,
    "title": "m / red",
    "price": "99.00",
    "sku": "",
    "position": 2,
    "grams": 0,
    "inventory_policy": "deny",
    "compare_at_price": "900.00",
    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "option1": "m",
    "option2": "red",
    "option3": null,
    "created_at": "2016-05-27T13:16:26-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-28T13:28:20-04:00",
    "taxable": false,
    "barcode": "",
    "image_id": 13217378823,
    "inventory_quantity": 1,
    "weight": 0,
    "weight_unit": "lb",
    "old_inventory_quantity": 1,
    "requires_shipping": true
  }
}


{
  "variant": {
    "id": 21717700871,
    "product_id": 6820646151,
    "title": "s / green",
    "price": "1000.00",
    "sku": "",
    "position": 1,
    "grams": 0,
    "inventory_policy": "deny",
    "compare_at_price": "1111.00",
    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "option1": "s",
    "option2": "green",
    "option3": null,
    "created_at": "2016-05-27T13:05:56-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-28T12:17:22-04:00",
    "taxable": true,
    "barcode": "",
    "image_id": 13160712135,
    "inventory_quantity": 2,
    "weight": 0,
    "weight_unit": "lb",
    "old_inventory_quantity": 2,
    "requires_shipping": true
  }
}


    {
  "variant": {
    "id": 21717690055,
    "product_id": 6821668807,
    "title": "Default Title",
    "price": "555.00",
    "sku": "",
    "position": 1,
    "grams": 0,
    "inventory_policy": "deny",
    "compare_at_price": "666.00",
    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
    "inventory_management": "shopify",
    "option1": "Default Title",
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "created_at": "2016-05-27T13:05:39-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-28T12:17:22-04:00",
    "taxable": true,
    "barcode": "",
    "image_id": null,
    "inventory_quantity": 2,
    "weight": 0,
    "weight_unit": "lb",
    "old_inventory_quantity": 2,
    "requires_shipping": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the variant's JSON as well?

Comment: I added the JSON for the three variants in the order in the question

Answer (score 0):

You created a fake order using the API. Fake orders like that don't transact money or trigger the usual internal checks and balances without some extra effort. Maybe if you tried adding a fulfillment to the order, Shopify might ding inventory levels? Seems like something to try anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to create a "real" order via the API? If not, and seeing as I need to create something as close to, if not a "real" order via the API, what would you advise?

Comment: By the term real I am pointing out that API generated orders cannot transact any money. They are containers for products, assigned to customers, at addresses, with some information concerning the how-much, but without any real payment info.

Comment: As for your problem, did you assign a fulfillment and solve your issue with inventory or not?

Comment: For business reasons, I cannot assign a fulfillment on the order, that is to be done by someone manually in the admin. How would you recommend I "trigger the usual internal checks and balances" for the order, including decreasing the stock quantity.

Comment: By making a fulfillment.

Comment: And since I can't make a fulfillment, my only option is to manually decrease the quantity via the API?

Comment: When creating an order in the admin, the stock quantity is automatically decreased, and yet none of the items have been fulfilled from what I can see, or are they??, thus, I am hoping there is another way...

Comment: so now your original question is answered and you're left with the simple task of making a fulfillment so as to mark them fulfilled. Walla Walla.